# Difference between "groff" and "gtroff"

Tags: groff

From the groff documentation:

> GNU 'troff' (or 'groff') is a system for typesetting documents.

Again:

> In this document, we consequently say 'gtroff' when talking about the
> GNU 'troff' program.

One more:

> 'groff' normally runs the 'gtroff' program and a postprocessor
> appropriate for the selected device.

So what is "gtroff" and what is the difference between "gtroff" and "groff"?

Comment: It sounds clear enough to me. The typesetting system `groff` runs several commands (programs), one of these being `gtroff` (`troff` with a `g` prepended, as described in the `groff(1)` manual and the manual that you quote).  It's similar to saying that `gcc` runs `cc1`, `as`, and `ld` while compiling, assembling, and linking your code. Not turning this into an answer as I'm not sure where the confusion lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtroff` is a component of `groff`.

`gtroff` is the GNU implementation of `troff` and `nroff`, the traditional roff processors; these process documents written in the roff formatting language and produce an intermediate output for device “postprocessors”. `gtroff` is described in detail [in its own section of the `groff` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/gtroff-Reference.html#gtroff-Reference). On Linux systems, it is usually installed as `troff`, not `gtroff`.

`groff` is the GNU implementation of a “complete” roff-based text processing system. It includes a number of pre-processors, which help produce roff starting with more abstract representations; these include `tbl` (for tables), `eqn` (for equations), `pic` (for diagrams). It also includes a number of post-processors, with support for ASCII, T<sub>E</sub>X DVI, HTML, PostScript, PDF output among others.

Traditional `troff` involves manually piping the input through the required pre-processors, then `troff` itself, then the appropriate post-processor. `groff` encapsulates all that; for example

```
groff -p -t -me -Tps example.me
```

pre-processes `example.me` with `pic` and `tbl`, then feeds the result to `troff` with the `me` macro package, and finally produces a PostScript file using `grops`.